# tsql set variable from select

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
declare @vlength varchar(50) 
set @vLength = 
  (select 
    CASE 
    WHEN
  SubString(SPSYS08.length, 0, CharIndex('"', SPSYS08.length)) > 0 
    AND SPSYS08.um = 'PC'
    THEN SubString(SPSYS08.length, 0, CharIndex('"', SPSYS08.length)) / 12
    else 1 
    end 

    From
  SPSYS08 Inner Join
  SPSYS07 On SPSYS08.loc_code = SPSYS07.loc_code And SPSYS08.so_no =
    SPSYS07.so_no)



Select
  SPSYS08.loc_code,
  SPSYS08.so_no,
  SPSYS08.line_no,
  SPSYS07.invoice_date

From
  SPSYS08 Inner Join
  SPSYS07 On SPSYS08.loc_code = SPSYS07.loc_code And SPSYS08.so_no =
    SPSYS07.so_no
Where
  SPSYS07.invoice_date = '20131206'
```

We are running on SQL server 2008. What I am trying to do is assign the length of a part to the vLength variable. Length is a char as it contains the inches (") symbol. I either get conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int or a select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval options.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Will your query return only one row always? You cannot assign multiple rows to a variable.

Comment: No, I need the length from multiple jobs.

Comment: How can you set multiple values to a single variable? How are you going to use this variable?

Comment: Can you add schema definition and sample data to your question.

Comment: I guess I have the wrong understanding of variables in SQL. We are trying to transition to it from an old system that uses COBAL. When we set variables in this query program it will loop through and change the variable assigment with each new job. I assume I'm going to have to manipulate this in Excel somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use a CTE for this instead:

```
;WITH Lengths AS
(select 
   Code,
   'L' = 
    CASE 
    WHEN
  SubString(SPSYS08.length, 0, CharIndex('"', SPSYS08.length)) > 0 
    AND SPSYS08.um = 'PC'
    THEN SubString(SPSYS08.length, 0, CharIndex('"', SPSYS08.length)) / 12
    else 1 
    end 

    From
  SPSYS08 Inner Join
  SPSYS07 On SPSYS08.loc_code = SPSYS07.loc_code And SPSYS08.so_no =
    SPSYS07.so_no)
```

Then you can

```
...
JOIN Lengths L
  ON L.Code = SomeOtherTable.Code
...
```

and get the length for each record.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this part should change

```
THEN SubString(SPSYS08.length, 0, CharIndex('"', SPSYS08.length)) / 12
```

the substring returns a string which you are trying to devide by 12 which will fail

you should probably use:

```
THEN CAST(SubString(SPSYS08.length, 0, CharIndex('"', SPSYS08.length)) AS INTEGER) / 12
```

but still you should make sure your substring returns a calue that is conveertable to integer

and second, it is possible that your select statement returns multiple rows which will cause your SET to fail, so you need to `SELECT TOP 1` or something in order to fix that part.

Comment: How can I double check this? When I add a cast I still get a conversion failed error...

Comment: right, so the substring is returning a character or something, you can forget about the cast and setting the variable, and just do the select and see what is the substring is returning